# Word for destroying someone's heart physically

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, *decapitate* means to cut off someone's head.

Is there a word that means to rip out someone's heart or destroy a heart?

Comment: COMMENTERS: Please provide answers in answers, not in comments.

Comment: Not "discard," though.

Comment: It's not clear to me if you're looking for a technical term or a colorful/poetic term. Are we talking Five Point Palm Exploding Heart technique a la Kill Bill Vol.2, or are we talking about a term that would be used in an autopsy to describe the outcome?

Comment: "Indy!  Cover your heart!" shouted Short Round as the bad guy attempted an unscheduled manual cardiectomy.

Comment: Cut it out with a spoon?

Comment: Just love this question for the answers it generated!

Comment: Off topic: If you can't describe it verbally, you can make use of the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmGOnXytAlw Here the protagonist is trying to explain creation of someone's heart as well as destroying your heart.

Comment: Historically, there's a lot of ripping out of hearts. decapitate is not medical, neither is: rip out someone's heart, though the latter is used metaphorically all the time. Anything with ectomy is either medical or forensic. What exactly is your context because they context guessing games get boring fast...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps there is no really appropriate single word commonly accepted for what you seek, and you should simply use the phrases 'heart removal' or 'heart extraction', which are the terms used on [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_sacrifice_in_Maya_culture) page on human sacrifice in Maya culture. However, there are terms used in medicine that may be of interest to you.

[Mosby's Medical Dictionary](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/cardiectomy) lists 'cardiectomy' to mean 'removal of the heart' or 'removal of the cardiac portion of the stomach'. [The Miller-Keane Encyclopedia and Dictionary of Medicine, Nursing, and Allied Health](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/cardiocentesis) lists 'cardiocentesis' as 'surgical puncture or incision of the heart'.

Comment: Thanks. I'm checking this cardiectomy as that's what sounds the best to me. But the other answers could be good too, it feels subjective.

Answer (score 19):

## Head : Behead :: Heart : *Beheart*

There exists a simple English word which stands in the same relation to the heart as *behead* to the head, and this word is of course ***beheart***.

It uses the privative *be-* prefix to mean that one is **de**prived of one’s heart.  We also find this prefix used that way in such verbs as *belimb* and *bereave*.

Nathaneel Whiting used it in a way that leaves no question as to its meaning. He is explaining the Bible verse 4:9 from the Song of Solomon (also known as Canticle of Canticles).

> *Cant.* 4.9. *Thou hast ravished my heart, my sister, my spouse* — thou hast **behearted** me, taken away my heart, as he that hath his head taken away, is said to be beheaded.

The verse he is explaining set in italics (his, not mine) and his explanation of said verse in roman (again his, not mine). That particular text can be found on page 162 of Whiting’s 
*Old Jacobs altar newly repaired, or, The saints triangle of dangers, deliverances and duties, personal and national, practically improved in many particulars, seasonable and experimental : being the answer of his own heart to God for eminent preservations, humbly recommended by way of teaching unto all...* published in 1664, as you might have surmised by now. :)

Other writers point out that “behearted” there is a literal translation from the Hebrew. There are many such observances, of which one is from Thomas Brooks on page 359 of his *A cabinet of choice jewels, or, A box of precious ointment, etc*, published in 1762:

> ‘Thou hast ravished my heart,’ (or thou hast behearted me, as the Hebrew runs) ‘my sister, my spouse;

[Wiktionary gives a definition for this word](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beheart) as meaning to enamour or to ravish citing Thomas Brooks as reprinted in 1866, plus another citation by a different author two years later.

Comment: Hope not to be befriended anytime soon ;-)

Comment: @AbraCadaver that would almost be as bad as getting disarmed and de-feeted!

Comment: @MasonWheeler For both of those there's the word _belimbed_. I think it was the subject of a previous EL&U question.

Answer (score 14):

The word "decardiate" has been used at least once before, presumably by analogy* to "decapitate."

This word apparently occurs in *Conan of the Isles* (1968), by L. Sprague de Camp and Lin Carter.

It's mentioned in the following [review by Ryan Harvey](http://realmofryan.blogspot.com/2010/08/book-review-conan-of-isles.html), who doesn't think much of the word:

> In places, their word choice falls flat or else strains too hard to
>   grasp an obscure term. I have never seen anyone use the word
>   “decardiate”—to remove the heart—in a work of fiction before, and I
>   doubt I will see it again.

---

*I think the analogy is not entirely legitimate, however, because *capit-* comes from the Latin word for "head," *[caput](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/caput#Latin)/capitis,* while *cardi-* comes from the *Greek* word for heart–the Latin word for heart is *[cor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cor#Latin), cordis.* *Cor* is the nominative and accusative form: derived words are typically built on the stem *cord-,* which occurs in the English words *accord, concord, discord, record, cordate, obcordate.* So theoretically the "heart" equivalent to *decapitate* would be "decordate" but all the results for this on Google are misspellings of the word "decorate".

There are actually some interesting Greek verbs derived from the noun *καρδία* that seem to have an appropriate meaning, such as *[καρδιουλκέω](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dkardioulke%2Fw) kardioulkéō* "draw the heart of the victim at a sacrifice" (also apparently a synonym *[καρδιουργέω](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dkardiourge%2Fw) kardiourgéō*)  and *[ἐκκαρδιόω](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3De)kkardio%2Fw) ekkardióō* "cut out the heart", but unfortunately there is no generally established way of adapting Greek verbs into English ones.

Comment: If you really must go for Latin, there’s always *excoriate*, except for that one originally deriving from *corium/corii* for skin not *cor/cordis* for heart. But honestly, who but thee and me would know the difference these days? :)

Comment: @tchrist but that's already a standard English word with a well-known, non-heart-removing meaning....

Comment: @Hellion I do realize that. I mentioned it only because for aeons I myself incorrectly assumed it derived from *cor*, heart not from *corium*, skin.  The extra *‑i‑* in *excor**i**ate* should have sufficed to enclue me but alas it took me decades to notice this.

Comment: "The word is half Latin and half Greek--nothing good can come of it!"

Comment: `(I'm not sure if the analogy is completely legitimate, however, because "capit-" comes from the Latin word for "head," caput/capitis, while "cardi-" comes from the Greek word for heart–the Latin word for heart is cor, cordis.)` Yeah, but using "de-cor-ate" to refer to removing someone's heart is going to cause more confusion than it's worth. :)

Comment: @HopelessN00b: exactly! (I also did a Google search for "decor**d**ate," and all of the results were misspellings of "decorate.") Regardless of its possible technical flaws in construction, "decardiate" at least seems to be less likely to cause confusion than a similarly formed all-Latin neologism.

Answer (score 10):

From [Aztec Sacrifice. Post-Conquest Nahua Painting, c. 1560...](https://www.csub.edu/~gsantos/img0012.html)

> *The Aztecs carved the heart out of an alive human war captive, dedicated his heart's blood to the sun, and ate his body in order to honor their gods and to preserve the world...
>
>   ...
>
>   ...THE **EXCARDIATED** VICTIMS WERE FLUNG DOWN THE STEPS OF THE PYRAMID*

<sup>(Sorry about the CAPS - they're in the original)</sup>

Obviously we don't often need such a term (and no - it's not in the full OED), but the above strikes me as as both easily understood<sup>1</sup> and unremarkable (so no need for "scare quotes").

---

<sup>1</sup> Most native speakers will be familiar with ***cardi-*** (relating to the heart) from words like ***cardiac arrest, cardiovascular disease, cardiogram.*** And the relevant senses of prefix ***ex-*** (away from) and suffix ***-ate*** (used to create a *verb* form) are reasonably common, so *given even minimal context*, this "neologism" should be reasonably transparent even on first encounter.

Comment: This is the correct answer. We want it to be based on Greek rather than Latin so we can use "cardi-" because that's better recognised, so it's excardiate.

Comment: May I suggest adding some etymology comparing excardiate to cardiectomy?

Comment: @Ben: Is my edit the kind of thing you had in mind? I would just say this is ELU, not ELL.

Comment: Yes, wonderful :-) I would upvote you had I not already done so!

Answer (score 1):

**Dishearten**

Not that I would vouch for it's common usage but a 1985 British Tabletop Roleplaying game called Dragon Warriors featured a Sorcerer spell called **Dishearten**.  Whilst the usual usage of the word is to demoralize, the meaning here was more literal, if the dice roll succeeded, the enemy's heart exploded within their chest (if it failed, they received minor damage as if from a painful kick to the chest).

As a verb meaning to remove a person's heart, Dishearten has the benefit of being well formed within English grammar, albeit with an unorthodox usage.  The usual sense being an antonym to such expressions as *take heart* or *be glad hearted*.

Comment: I would use this word normally, it's certainly in common usage. I'm disheartened you think it's not!

Comment: That sounds more like a pun than normal usage.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey: I think b.p.'s just saying that the literal meaning is not common usage.

Comment: @r256 I agree... though depending on tone, this isn't necessarily a bad thing...

Comment: @r256: As suməlic says, the literal meaning isn't standard though I feel it is well-formed within English structural rules.  You are right that it is in fact a pun but unlike most puns, by virtual of its construction, the pun has a correct and intended meaning if taken literally, which is undeniably an unorthodox usage.